# Python Game is not ending

Tags: python

```
ans = True
while ans:
    print("""
    1.Add a Student
    2.Delete a Student
    3.Look Up Student Record
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans = input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans == "1":
        print("\n Student Added")
    elif ans == "2":
        print("\n Student Deleted")
    elif ans == "3":
        print("\n Student Record Found")
    elif ans == "4":
        print("\n Goodbye")
    elif ans != "":
        print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
```

Comment: What did you do differently in the code for the 4 case that made you expect it would end the loop?

Comment: It **will** end, if you just hit <Enter>.  Do you know why?  Do you know about `break`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `while` loop condition is testing the True/False-ness of an input string, which is probably always `True`.

Comment: No, there is a condition where `ans` is *considered* false, but it certainly isn't when `ans == '4'`.